Bolding existing text on a PDF while maintaining formatting in Python
I'm trying to recreate a Chrome extension called Bionic Reading that does not work on downloaded PDF files myself. Essentially, I'd like to bold the first few letters of every word on a PDF while keeping (roughly) the existing formatting & images. I've tried to utilize pypdf and ReportLab for this, but neither seems to provide the functionality I'm looking for. Any ideas?
I was able to bold the text of each word, but I wasn't able to simply edit the same PDF (or make a copy and edit that), but rather just copy the text and alter it. Formatting proved to be the main issue, as well as image retention (I'm hoping to use this to read research papers, so formatting and figures are very important).

I am not surprised that this is not supported by these libraries as this tends to be rather uncommon. While it should be doable, a clean solution sounds rather complex, as you basically have to analyze the plain text operators and modify them in a way that your desired characters use the bold font variant, given that it is indeed available. The easiest way I see is to get the bounding boxes and font params of the text (using MuPDF, ...) to replace and to re-draw it with a bold font after hiding the original text (for example generating an overlay with reportlab and adding it with pypdf).

Couldn't you otherwise mark the text - like underlining or highlighting? What makes bolding it so indispensable?
